# FAST Computation of Integer Basis for Kernel of a Matrix Using GPU

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, linear-algebra, multicore

Input: a `n times m` matrix `A` with integer entries. For example consider the matrix

```
A = [[2,1,0],[0,1,2]]
```

Output: an integer basis for the kernel/null space of `A`. For example for the above matrix, an integer basis is

```
[[1,-2,1]]
```

I am using ideas from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053885/calculating-rational-basis-for-the-nullspace-using-numpy), to first compute a rational basis and then compute an integer basis by multiplying with the lcm of denominators, with the following (`Python 2.7`) code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix,lcm
from fractions import Fraction

def ker_int_basis(B):
    BKer = 1.0*np.array(Matrix(B).nullspace())
    Bk =[]
    for basis in BKer:
        l = lcm(map(lambda x: Fraction(x).limit_denominator().denominator,map(str,basis)))
        basis = map(int,l*basis)
        Bk.append(basis)    
    Bk = np.array(Bk)
    return Bk
```

It works on small examples. But the above code is tediously slow and the matrices I have are `10000 times 500` or bigger. The above code doesn't output even after hours of running.

**How can I make the code faster?** I would prefer a GPU implementation, considering the matrices are very very large. A multi-core CPU will also be an improvement. Even suggestions to use loops and data structures more efficiently in the above code are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy is using [Gaussian Elimination](https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/_modules/sympy/matrices/matrices.html) to compute the null space of `B`. This is $O(n^3)$, and I assume that this computation is the bottle neck in your code (but it would be worth checking).

Gaussian elimination can be parallelized by doing all eliminations simultaneously. The algorithm for GE is relatively straightforward, and there are many implementations for floating point numbers out there. However, I didn't see other symbolic packages which would do this using rational numbers or integers in my brief search (although you could probably implement this relatively easily).

Another thing you could try in order to parallize the task without rewriting an algorithm to find the null space is to split the matrix into two sets of rows, compute the null space of each, and then compute a basis for the intersection of the computed null spaces. This would work well if each of the sets of rows have relatively small null spaces, but not so well if they both return very large null spaces.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I will have to implement Gaussian Elimination.